# Display flex with gap not working in Safari (IPhone)

Tags: css, safari

I need to render a list of products in a column. I used display: flex with `gap`. In all browsers, it works fine but in Safari the `gap` is not working. There are no spaces (gaps) between products.

How can I solve this problem?

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/bsx2ru5L)

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 1.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.product {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="product">
    Ahoj
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    Ahoj
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    Ahoj
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    Ahoj
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    Ahoj
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    Ahoj
  </div>

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Works fine on my phone, iPhone SE with the latest iOS and Safari. What device, iOS, and Safari version are you on?

Comment: Only the latest versions of safari can render it. Not the older ones

Answer (score 3):

Replace flex with grid because flex gap is not supported in safari version below 14
use :

```
display: grid;
grid-gap: 1rem;
gap: 1rem
```

Answer (score 0):

After update IOS (including safari) problem solved.